# What are the elegant ways to do MixIns in Python?

Tags: python, mixins

I need to find an elegant way to do 2 kinds of MixIns.

**First:**

```
class A(object):
    def method1(self):
        do_something()
```

Now, a `MixInClass` should make `method1` do this: `do_other()` -> `A.method1()` -> `do_smth_else()` - i.e. basically "wrap" the older function. I'm pretty sure there must exist a good solution to this.

**Second:**

```
class B(object):
    def method1(self):
        do_something()
        do_more()
```

In this case, I want `MixInClass2` to be able to inject itself between `do_something()` and `do_more()`, i.e.: `do_something()` -> `MixIn.method1` -> `do_more()`. I understand that probably this would require modifying `class B` - that's ok, just looking for simplest ways to achieve this.

These are pretty trivial problems and I actually solved them, but my solution is tainted.

Fisrt one by using `self._old_method1 = self.method1(); self.method1() = self._new_method1();` and writing `_new_method1()` that calls to `_old_method1()`.

Problem: multiple MixIns will all rename to _old_method1 and it is inelegant.

Second MixIn one was solved by creating a dummy method `call_mixin(self): pass` and injecting it between calls and defining `self.call_mixin()`. Again inelegant and will break on multiple MixIns..

Any ideas?

---

Thanks to Boldewyn, I've found elegant solution to first one (I've forgot you can create decorators on-the-fly, without modifying original code):

```
class MixIn_for_1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.method1 = self.wrap1(self.method1)
        super(MixIn_for_1, self).__init__()

    def wrap1(self, old):
        def method1():
            print "do_other()"
            old()
            print "do_smth_else()"
        return method1
```

Still searching for ideas for second one (this idea won't fit, since I need to inject inside of old method, not outside, like in this case).

---

Solution for second is below, replacing "pass_func" with `lambda:0`.

Comment: For your 2nd question, does mixin.method1 needs parameters, and if so, do these parameters depend on variables/return values in do_something()? And finally, does do_more() need the result of your mixin?

Comment: No, do_more() doesn't need result. The arguments? I probably only need "self", which should be passed anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to implement MixInClass1, MixinClass2:

Decorators are useful when you need to wrap many functions. Since `MixinClass1` needs to wrap only one function, I think it is clearer to monkey-patch:

Using double underscores for `__old_method1` and `__method1` plays a useful role in `MixInClass1`. Because of Python's name-mangling convention, using the double underscores localizes these attributes to `MixinClass1` and allows you to use the very same attribute names for other mix-in classes without causing unwanted name-collisions.

```
class MixInClass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__old_method1,self.method1=self.method1,self.__method1
        super(MixInClass1, self).__init__()        
    def __method1(self):
        print "pre1()"
        self.__old_method1()
        print "post1()"

class MixInClass2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MixInClass2, self).__init__()        
    def method1_hook(self):
        print('MixIn method1')

class Foo(MixInClass2,MixInClass1):
    def method1(self):
        print "do_something()"
        getattr(self,'method1_hook',lambda *args,**kw: None)()
        print "do_more()"

foo=Foo()
foo.method1()
```

Comment: The first solution is exactly the same I described in question.
The second one is clever, assuming `Foo` is `B` and pass_func is `lambda:0`.

Comment: @Slava: If you use `pass_func`, then you will not have to change `Foo` if you later decide to pass arguments to `method1_hook`. If you use `lambda: 0` then you would have to change it to something like `lambda x,y,z: 0`.

Comment: 1. What is `pass_func`?  2. Can't we just do `lambda *args, **kwargs:0` ?

Answer (score 5):

I think, that can be handled in quite a Pythonic way using [decorators](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808). ([PEP 318](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/), too)

Comment: Thanks, that solves my first problem. I did in fact think of decorators, but I had forgotten that I could construct decorators as deco(method), instead of @deco. The latter required modifying original code.